# After Enabling Oracle Net Encryption Standard JDBC Connection Possible

Tags: oracle, networking, encryption, jdbc

Used Oracle Net Manager to enable network encryption.

sqlnet.ora file:

> SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT = required
>
> SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
>
> SSL_VERSION = 0
>
> SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER = required
>
> SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE
>
> SQLNET.CRYPTO_SEED = '0123456789'
>
> SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT= (AES256)
>
> SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT= (AES256)
>
> ...

Java Code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("oracle.net.encryption_client", "required");
props.put("oracle.net.encryption_types_client", "AES256");
props.put("user", "scott");
props.put("password", "tiger");
```

Using other algorithm names e.g. AES128: props.put("oracle.net.encryption_types_client", "AES128"); outputs ORA-12650. This is OK. But putting only user and password to Properties connection is possible:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("user", "scott");
props.put("password", "tiger");
```

How to disable standard connection whenever Oracle Net Encryption is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't set the "oracle.net.encryption_types_client" property in the JDBC thin driver, by default the driver will "**accept**" encryption and because you have made encryption "**required**" on the server, the encryption will be turned on. To summarize, if you "**require**" encryption on the server that will make all the connections use encryption. Any client that doesn't support encryption will fail to connect.

This ASO negotiation is explained in this [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e40393/asoconfg.htm#ASOAG020), look at the table "**Table 9-2 Encryption and Data Integrity Negotiations**". By default the JDBC thin driver accepts encryption.